# Execute a function after scroll to a div only 1 time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, window

I want to execute a function only 1 time after scroll to a certain div, but the way i do it below, it keeps triggering that function after scroll.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
                var hT = $('#test').offset().top,
                hH = $('#test').outerHeight(),
                wH = $(window).height(),
                wS = $(this).scrollTop();
                if ((wS >= (hT+hH-wH)) && (i < 4)){
                  myfunction();
                }
              });
```

I want myfunction() to be executed only 1 time 
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

After `myfunction` is executed once, remove the `scroll` handler

```
$(window).on('scroll.myfunction', function() {
  var hT = $('#test').offset().top,
    hH = $('#test').outerHeight(),
    wH = $(window).height(),
    wS = $(this).scrollTop();
  if ((wS >= (hT + hH - wH)) && (i < 4)) {
    myfunction();
    $(window).off('scroll.myfunction');
  }
});
```